# How to create this grunge texture effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am making a logo in photoshop and want to add this old spotted vintage type of filter. Can anyone let me know how? Specifically the light dots on the black:

[image]

I'm using photoshop CS4

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30147/how-to-create-a-grunge-spray-paint-text-effect-in-photoshop

Answer (score 7):

Scan in a texture you like, then use it as a layer mask. Google "PhotoShop Grunge Layer Mask" and you'll find dozens of examples and tutorials:

https://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop+grunge+layer+mask

Comment: Or just take a photo of some cleanish concrete, and mess around with the curves/levels

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach (there are several ways to do almost *anything* in Photoshop) would be to create a dark gray layer -- maybe H 0, S 0, B 15 -- above your shape, and clip it to that layer. Add noise (lots -- 20 to 30% or more, Gaussian). Blur slightly. Add a Levels adjustment layer and clip it to your noise layer, then work the sliders until you have the effect you want. (Hint: be extreme!) You can get a subtle granite texture, a star field or anything between very easily.

I'm pretty sure this technique comes from an old Deke McClelland tutorial that builds a versatile, changeable background using essentially this technique. I searched around for it, but can't find it currently. I do have just such a Photoshop file, though, that I use for anything from star fields to grunge to wildly colored textures. Build it once, and it's a resource forever.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.deke.com/content/deke%E2%80%99s-techniques-009-building-a-synthetic-starfield-scratch). Also maybe related/useful: [this](http://www.deke.com/content/dekes-techniques-004-creating-a-hammered-metal-background), [this](http://www.deke.com/content/dekes-techniques-244-creating-psychedelic-fabric-photoshop) and [this](http://www.deke.com/content/dekes-techniques-002-branding-type-a-texture). Just researched for your convenience to embed in related content.