# How to create a grunge/spray-paint text effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects

Please show me how I can achieve below effect for text:

[image: sample]

Those random ink spray spots, shapes are basically transparent so it will show the color of whatever the background is (black in this case).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Huy! We have a couple of similar questions, see for example: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/how-to-create-this-grunge-texture-effect/8819#8819 or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16075/grunge-effect-for-vinyl/16077#16077

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD. I believe you would call it "grunge", and a search for grunge text effects should give you lots of alternatives.

Comment: I took a look at the older posts, and don't really like the approaches.  Both want you to overlay a grunge image.  Why not find some good grunge brushes and paint in a layer mask?  This way you would have much more control over where your grunge effects appear on your type.

Comment: Thank you. Woa, searching for "photoshop grunge effect" gives me a lot of methods. Thanks :)

Comment: @cclark413 overlaying on image and putting image onto the mask is same thing.

Comment: @joojaa No, it is not.  The brush would allow you more control over the effect - it would be much more work to make an image have the same "functionality" and versatility.

Comment: @cclark413 err... one click and paste?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layer mask on your text and then apply a texture like the one linked below. You can also use that mask on a group folder. The part you want to become the "grunge texture" should appear in black on our mask.

This will make the texture transparent and you can move the mask around to adjust it where you want on your text!

http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-grunge-06_100726_Grunge_06.png

[image: eExample with layer mask and grunge texture]

Answer (score 0):

You can download paint splatter brushes and install them. A quick Google search reveals how to install them.

Comment: You could do that, but you still haven't explained how you would use the brushes.